# Mysql Float value insertion using pure ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby

I've a ruby code like the following:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :password => "root")
client.query("CREATE TABLE Customers
                      (
                        Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        Name VARCHAR(25),
                        CurrentDate DATE,
                        SourceCurrency VARCHAR(25),
                        TargetCurrency VARCHAR(25),
                        SourceAmount FLOAT(23,7),
                        TargetAmount FLOAT(23,7)
                      )"
                    )

    target_amount = source_amount * 0.7477

    client.select_db "project6"
    client.query("INSERT INTO Customers (Name, CurrentDate, SourceCurrency, TargetCurrency, SourceAmount, TargetAmount)VALUES(#{client.escape(customer_name)}, #{(Date.today)}, 'EUR', 'GBP', #{(source_amount)}, #{(target_amount)})")
    client.close
```

Here `source_amount` and `target_amount` both are **float**. In my **project6** table the data type for SourceAmount & TargetAmount is float(23,7).

But whenever I run this code error occurs:

```
Uncaught exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '23:39:43 +0600, 'EUR', 'GBP', 120.0, 89.724)' at line 1
```

if I set `customer_name`=**"emu"** then other error

```
Unknown column 'emu' in 'field list' (Mysql2::Error)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The problem isn't the float. It's the time format. To SQL, you've given two arguments in place of the one for the current date: `23:39:43` and `+0600`. You need to use Ruby time/date formatting to give SQL what it wants for that. The attribute is `CurrentDate` but you're using `Time.now` which, by default, gives the time and the time zone as outputs.

Comment: @lurker, I've removed the 'time.now` from inserting. now, it gives a new error: unknown column if I give `customer_name`= "Emu"

Comment: If you remove the `time.now` from inserting, you also need to remove the `CurrentDate` attribute from the attribute list. Also, please add any details to your question by editing your question and adding that information (don't change what you have, just add more). It's too difficult to follow code changes in comments.

Comment: The string needs to have quotes on it in the query. Try, `'#{client.escape(customer_name)}'` instead of just `#{client.escape(customer_name)}`. If it doesn't evaluate the `#{...}` in that case, then use: `"INSERT INTO Customers (Name, CurrentDate, SourceCurrency, TargetCurrency, SourceAmount, TargetAmount) VALUES (' " + client.escape(customer_name) + "', #{(Date.today)}, 'EUR', 'GBP', #{(source_amount)}, #{(target_amount)})"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

(1) You are providing the output of `Time.now` (which is time of day plus the time zone offset with a space delimiter by default, *e.g.*, `23:39:43 +0600`) to an SQL DATE attribute, which doesn't match. You need to provide a date.

(2) The value for the `Name` attribute needs to be quoted. Otherwise, SQL thinks you're referring to an attribute name. So if you have `customer_name = 'emu'`, your current query is only getting `emu` as the value, not `'emu'`. You can fix that a few different ways. For example:

```
client.query("INSERT INTO Customers (Name, CurrentDate, SourceCurrency, TargetCurrency, SourceAmount, TargetAmount) VALUES ('#{client.escape(customer_name)}', #{(Date.today)}, 'EUR', 'GBP', #{(source_amount)}, #{(target_amount)})")
```

Or...

```
client.query("INSERT INTO Customers (Name, CurrentDate, SourceCurrency, TargetCurrency, SourceAmount, TargetAmount) VALUES ('" + client.escape(customer_name) + "', #{(Date.today)}, 'EUR', 'GBP', #{(source_amount)}, #{(target_amount)})")
```

Comment: @Emu cool. I added that suggestion to my full answer for completeness. I wasn't sure if it would work because, in some contexts in Ruby, the single quotes don't allow interpretation of the `#{...}` expression. My second option would get around that.